# How to simulate an "Focus" and "typing" Events

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, vba, web-scraping

Trying to simulate onfocus and typing event, but it not work

```vb
Sub Login(MyLogin, MyPass)
    Dim IEapp As InternetExplorer
    Dim IeDoc As Object
    Dim ieTable As Object
    TaskKill "iexplore.exe"

    Set IEapp = New InternetExplorer
        IEapp.Visible = True
            IEapp.Navigate "https://example.com/portal/en/login"
        Do While IEapp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop: Do Until IEapp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
        Set IeDoc = IEapp.Document
        With IeDoc.forms(2)


            .Name.Value = MyLogin
            .Name.Focus
            .FireEvent ("onkeypress")
            .FireEvent ("onchange")


            .Password.Value = MyPass
            .Password.Focus
            .FireEvent ("onkeypress")
            .FireEvent ("onchange")
       End With
        IeDoc.getElementsByClassName("form__button form__button--login-site")(1).Click

End Sub
```

How to call focus and typing events? Sendkeys is bad solution as it have Excel bug with Numlock

Comment: What is happening?  Might be best to check `IEapp.Busy` and `IEapp.Readystate` in the same loop

Comment: I got error `E-mail address is obligatory `, after i manualy focus email and type somethig error is gone

Comment: What lines are working as you expect, i.e. adding data to the form?  Why do you focus after adding the text?

Comment: because it page requirement to focus field and type from keyboard

Comment: so maybe you need focus before adding the text?

Comment: Result the same I tried all possible combination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event listeners for those elements indicate input events are watched for. You can create those and then fire.

**Internet Explorer:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub LogIn()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.darsgo.si/portal/en/login"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector(".LoginHeader + p a").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim event_onInput As Object
        Set event_onInput = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        event_onInput.initEvent "input", True, False

        With .document.querySelector("#name")
            .Value = "bobBuilder@banana.com"
            .dispatchEvent event_onInput
        End With
        With .document.querySelector("#password")
            .Value = "something"
            .dispatchEvent event_onInput
        End With

        .document.querySelector(".form__button").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Stop
        .Quit
    End With     
End Sub
```

---

**Selenium:**

If you are prepared to use [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) it works just fine as follows.
After installing selenium go VBE > Tools > References and add a reference to selenium type library. You should use the latest ChromeDriver. The ChromeDriver may come installed already in the selenium folder - otherwise it needs to be added there.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Login()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://www.darsgo.si/portal/en/login"
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .FindElementByCss(".choose-language-popup__list li:nth-of-type(2) a").Click
        .FindElementByCss(".choose-language-popup__icon-continue").Click
        .FindElementByCss("p.registerHeader a").Click
        .FindElementById("name").SendKeys "bob@builder.com"
        .FindElementById("password").SendKeys "verySecret"
        .FindElementByCss(".form__button").Click

        Stop

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Just for curiosity sake, would you care to explain more in depth what the code in your first snippet does? quarySelector gets the first element that matches the specifications, but where did you get `".LoginHeader + p a"` from? Is that readable in the website's source?

Comment: The page has event listeners watching those elements for input events. The code simply adds those events to the page and triggers them after the values have been inputed. This was what was being triggered manually by adding text to the field.

Comment: Nice, I get the theory behind it now. Putting it into practice will require some more research (and trial and error) ... :)

Comment: See https://codedocu.com/Office-365/Access/Controls/web-Browser/Vba,-HTMLSelect_colon_-FireEvent-OnChange-or-DispatchEvent?1890   When you right click on the input elements and observe in the dev tools elements window you should be able to see the listeners listed.

Comment: Thanks, I see where to get the elements from, still raises a question where `".LoginHeader + p a"` comes from.

Comment: when I initially access the start url I have to click a link for already registered login as opposed to create an account. If you step through with F8 hopefully you should see this.

Comment: I am stepping through, come by that same screen, but I just can't seem to find that name in the dev tools elements window. Either way, there is a small error in your code with `.Quit`.

Comment: It is a css selector. Say you open in google chrome > elements tab > select any html element > press Ctrl + F > enter the selector in the search box > hit enter. You have to be at the right url though. I will paste a link in a moment.

Comment: See the following: note the highlighted element and the selector in the top right search box https://filebin.net/wtq37bhygmmb90pl

Comment: note from the bottom of the window you can see the element path. This indicates there is actually a better css selector of simply: p.registerHeader a

Comment: ahhhhh now I see. I was confused cause the other elements name and password were so clear to me. I have zero css/java/HTML background, learned VBA just practicing, but these type of things still amazes me! Thank you for the explaination. I hope to be able to use it in the future! P.S. dont forget to edit your `.Quit` ;)

Comment: thank you. See the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors and play with this https://flukeout.github.io/

Comment: Maybe you can solve problem with wicked-crypt site? How to get dynamics links with dynamics elements

Comment: Please post a new question and leave a link and I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work for you:

```vb
Sub Login()
    Dim IEapp As InternetExplorer
    Dim IeDoc as Object
    Dim ieTable As Object

    TaskKill "iexplore.exe"
    Set IEapp = New InternetExplorer
        IEapp.Visible = True
            IEapp.navigate "https://example.com/portal/en/login"
        Do While IEapp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop: Do Until IEapp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
        Set IeDoc = IEapp.document
        With IeDoc.forms(2)
            .elements("name").Value = MyLogin
            .elements("password").Value = MyPass
       End With
       IeDoc.forms(2).submit
End Sub
```

Comment: result the same, as page want to user focus and type into field

Comment: form submits, but not going to login as there are no focused and typed fields controled by javascript, I think submit goes after click but not by submit as it will be prevent.default

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin, that's unfortunate. Was worth a try. I'm very new to the VBA-internet connection and am very curious to know if solution provided by Qharr worked for you.