# VBA Excel: data in the inputbox WEB

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I need help on the following code.

I can put the data in the inputbox but it gives an error when submitting.

I think the problem comes from the "autocomplete" event

```
Sub VDF()
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

        IE.Visible = True
        IE.navigate "https://www.vodafone.pt/pacotes/cobertura/"
        Do While IE.Busy
        Loop
        
        Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
        
        'Alternative to Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Do While HTMLInput Is Nothing
            Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("checkCoverButton")
        Loop

        'Phone
        Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("phone-number")
        HTMLInput.Value = "911111111"

        'CP
        Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("postalCode")
        HTMLInput.Value = Worksheet(1).Cells(4, 4)
        'image 1 the code runs so far
        
        'Submit form btn Pesquisar
        Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("checkCoverButton")
        HTMLInput.Click
End Sub
```

The form fields are written after running the procedure but when submitting the form it gives an error as if the fields were blank

[written mobile number and postal code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLtHd.png)

[After Submit form btn Pesquisar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBCEz.png)

Comment: Please leave the declarations in rather than just put `Dim ...`. otherwise, people have to type it and guess what declaration types you used. Please also include the error and indicate on which line it occurs (the final click?)

Comment: The input fields have events. You must trigger the change event after paste your text. Or the keypress event or another one, I don't know. Look here how you can do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294113/automate-ie-via-excel-to-fill-in-a-dropdown-and-continue/63299608#63299608

Comment: I used the code and it doesn't work
`HTMLInput.FireEvent ("onkeypress")`
`HTMLInput.FireEvent ("onchange")`
`HTMLInput.Value = "911111111"` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763526/how-to-simulate-an-focus-and-typing-events)

Comment: I used the code and it doesn't work either! =(  
`Set event_onInput =HTMLDoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")`  `event_onInput.initEvent "input", True, False`  `Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("phone-number")` 
 `HTMLInput.Value = "911111111"`  `HTMLInput.dispatchEvent event_onInput`

Comment: `FireEvent` is outdated and doesn't work with most pages today. Do you had taken a look in my link? Use the sub `TriggerEvent()` from my post, look in the makro above how to work with it and look in the screenshots below how to check the events.

Comment: Great! Problem solved. The first time when I analyzed the code I thought it was not applicable because it is a dropdown but after your tip I decided to risk it and done. Thanks for your time @Zwenn  Solution: Added `Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, HTMLInput, "change")`

Comment: That are good news :-) The `TriggerEvent()` sub is universal useable for all HTML events. The HTML element doesn't matter.  In the macro of the linked post are also text input fields with events.

Comment: Yea! After seeing it better, I realized the detail and the excellent job of explaining it step by step. Congratulations on the great work! I'm new to this community. Do I need to do something to close the question or something else?

Comment: If there were an answer that solved your problem, you could mark it as a solution. But here we have only exchanged a few comments. So the thread just stays like this. It doesn't matter in this case because there is no new insight that other users would benefit from.